# C++ destructor leaks with dynamic memory

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, destructor, dynamic-memory-allocation

```
// Class
ArrayIntVector : IntVector{
private:
  int *data;
  int dataCapacity;
  int numElements;
  void check_invariants() const;
}

// Constructor
ArrayIntVector::ArrayIntVector(int initCapacity)
    : dataCapacity(initCapacity), numElements(0) {
    data = new int[dataCapacity];
    check_invariants();
}

// Destructor
ArrayIntVector::~ArrayIntVector() {
    check_invariants();

    delete[] data;
    data = 0;
}

int main(){

    IntVector *v = new ArrayIntVector(5);
    // testing class functions
    // push_back, pop_back, empty, index, grow
    delete v;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting leaks. When I use valgrind I get the following:

HEAP SUMMARY:
  in use at exit: 20 bytes in 1 blocks
  total heap usage: 7 allocs, 7 frees, 1,284 bytes allocated

20 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
  at 0x4A07152: operator new[](unsigned long) (vg_replace_malloc.c:363)
  by 0x400DBE: ArrayIntVector::ArrayIntVector(int) (IntVector.cpp:12)
  by 0x401142: main (lab09.cpp:8)

Comment: Please provide a complete minimal working example that reproduces the problem. Otherwise it is impossible to tell what the problem is as we can only guess about what you do in the code you did not show.

Comment: You don't have to set `data` to null after deletion in the destructor. When the destructor is executed there is no more `data`.

Comment: Does your code throw any exception in the `// do stuff` part?

Comment: You are making a pointer of type IntVector and assigning it an ArrayIntVector.  Assuming that it is a subclass is the destructor marked as virtual?

Comment: I was told to set pointers to null so that you cannot accidentally access the location you just deleted things from. It does not throw any exceptions. The base class and derived class destructors are marked as virtual in the header file.

Comment: But who can access `data` after the object has been destroyed?

Comment: Ruled out the possibility of a non-virtual destructor and considering you have 7 allocs and 7 frees, maybe the line `data = 0` confuses valgrind? It's very unlikely but if you don't post more code is hard to tell where the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your destructor is not virtual. Declare the destructor as virtual.

Comment: It is declared as virtual in the header file

Comment: @user2961535: Do you declared `IntVector`'s destructor as virtual?

Comment: Is the base class destructor, IntVector,  declared as virtual?

Comment: Yes, all the destructors are declared virtual in the header file

Comment: IN THE HEADER FILE
// Destructor for IntVector (base class)
  virtual ~IntVector() { };

// Destructor for ArrayIntVector (derived class)
  virtual ~ArrayIntVector();

all of the other functions that are used are declared in the header file, including the constructor for the derived class

Comment: Is check_invariants virtual? And what does it do?

Comment: no, that is a private static member function of ArrayIntVector. It checks that the data is not a void pointer, numElements is between 0 and dataCapacity, inclusive, and that dataCapacity is >= 0

Comment: @user2961535 How can a parameter-less static member function check `data`? Is `data` static too?